# How to build a JSON object iterating over dict?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

There is a function, which iterates over a dict with parameters for GA API, on the basis of the request type (indicated in this dict), fetches additional parameters and as result we have a new dict.

Tables are fetched from a SQL table and are in pandas df format

metrics for Metrics table
dimensions for Dimensions table

```
def ga_config(dimensions, metrics, ga_config_1):

    data_finish = {} # finish dict with all parameters

    for k in ga_config_1.keys(): # check the type of the request (ga_standard or ga_users)
        metrics_type = metrics.loc[(metrics['request_type'] == k)] # get the rows for this type of request
        metrics_list = metrics_type['metric_name'].to_list()  # convert them to a list
        dimensions_type = dimensions.loc[(dimensions['request_type'] == k)]
        dimensions_list = dimensions_type['dimension_name'].to_list()

        dimensions_js = [{
            'name': x,
        } for x in dimensions_list]   # add 'name' in order to make a request later

        metrics_js = [{
            'expressions': x,
        } for x in metrics_list] # add 'expressions' in order to make a request later

        """
        Iterates over a dict with the rest of the parameters like view_id and dates

        """
        for k, v in ga_config_1.items():
            data =  {'view_id': v['view_id'],
        'start_date': v['start_date'],
        'end_date': v['end_date'],
            'metrics': metrics_js,
             'dimensions': dimensions_js
            }
        data_finish['view_id_' + v['view_id']] = data


        return data_finish


# ga_config_1  parameters: 2 types of request, but can be more: ga_standard and ga_users

ga_config_1 = {'ga_standard' : {'view_id': '115126931',
                           'start_date': '2019-01-01',
                           'end_date': '2019-01-01'},


              'ga_standard' : {'view_id': '1151269318',
                           'start_date': '2019-01-01',
                           'end_date': '2019-01-01'},
              'ga_users' : {'view_id': '1151269399',
                           'start_date': '2019-01-01',
                           'end_date': '2019-01-01'}}
```

If type ga_standard: 
dimensions: ga:year
metrics: ga:sessions, ga:bounces

If type ga:users:
dimensions: ga:userType
metrics: ga:users

But the result is only the last parameter in ga_config_1

```
data_finish = {
'view_id_1151269399': {'view_id': '1151269399',
  'start_date': '2019-01-01',
  'end_date': '2019-01-01',
  'metrics': [{'expressions': 'ga:users'}],
  'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:userType'}]}}
```

But the desired output should consist all of them

```
data_finish ={

{'view_id_115126931': {'view_id': '115126931',
  'start_date': '2019-01-01',
  'end_date': '2019-01-01',
  'metrics': [{'expressions': 'ga:users'}, {'expressions': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expressions': 'ga:bounces'}],
  'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:year'}]}},

{'view_id_1151269318': {'view_id': '1151269318',
  'start_date': '2019-01-01',
  'end_date': '2019-01-01',
  'metrics': [{'expressions': 'ga:users'}, {'expressions': 'ga:sessions'}, {'expressions': 'ga:bounces'}],
  'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:year'}]}},

{'view_id_1151269399': {'view_id': '1151269399',
  'start_date': '2019-01-01',
  'end_date': '2019-01-01',
  'metrics': [{'expressions': 'ga:users'}],
  'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:userType'}]}
}
```

I know there is some stupid mistake but can't get it

Answer (score 0):

The assignment to a key of `data_finish` should be inside the inner `for` loop, while the `return` statement should be outside the outer `for` loop:

```
def ga_config(dimensions, metrics, ga_config_1):
    data_finish = {}  # finish dict with all parameters

    for k in ga_config_1.keys():  # check the type of the request (ga_standard or ga_users)
        metrics_type = metrics.loc[(metrics['request_type'] == k)]  # get the rows for this type of request
        metrics_list = metrics_type['metric_name'].to_list()  # convert them to a list
        dimensions_type = dimensions.loc[(dimensions['request_type'] == k)]
        dimensions_list = dimensions_type['dimension_name'].to_list()

        dimensions_js = [{
            'name': x,
        } for x in dimensions_list]  # add 'name' in order to make a request later

        metrics_js = [{
            'expressions': x,
        } for x in metrics_list]  # add 'expressions' in order to make a request later

        """
        Iterates over a dict with the rest of the parameters like view_id and dates

        """
        for k, v in ga_config_1.items():
            data = {'view_id': v['view_id'],
                    'start_date': v['start_date'],
                    'end_date': v['end_date'],
                    'metrics': metrics_js,
                    'dimensions': dimensions_js
                    }
            data_finish['view_id_' + v['view_id']] = data

    return data_finish
```

Comment: Hello, I tried but it returns 2 and 3 element of ga_config_1 with dimensions and metrics for the third (ga_users)((